# How to mock init of helper class

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I am having trouble with checking if an object is being constructed with the proper params from another instance of an object. In the below example, I am trying to create an instance of `B` within an instance of `A`. I want to check the parameter being used in the constructor of `B` inside of the `A` instance. When I run the test below, I get:

```
AssertionError: assert None
[CPython36:setup:stdout] E        +  where None = <bound method NonCallableMock.assert_called_with of <MagicMock name='B' id='139968329210736'>>(4)
[CPython36:setup:stdout] E        +    where <bound method NonCallableMock.assert_called_with of <MagicMock name='B' id='139968329210736'>> = <MagicMock name='B' id='139968329210736'>.assert_called_with
```

I am not quite sure what I am doing wrong here and have looked at other stack overflow posts, but have not been able to solve my issue.

b.py:

```
class B(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def square(self):
        return x * x
```

a.py:

```
from b import B

class A(object):
    def foo(self):
        b = B(4)
        b.square()
```

test_a.py:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

from a import A

class TestA(unittest.TestCase):  

    @patch('a.B')
    def test_foo(self, mock_b):
        self.a = A()
        self.a.foo()
        assert mock_b.assert_called_with(4)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method `assert_called_with` returns None, so what your are doing is like doing

```
assert None
```

And that's basically the error message you are getting.

You can just use

```
mock_b.assert_called_with(4)
```

Which has an assert internally and pytest will display it correctly in case of failure. Try to check it by changing the argument value.

Alternatively, if you prefer to write the assert yourself, you can do something like this:

```
from unittest.mock import call
assert mock_b.call_args_list == [call(4)]
```

Or just the last call:

```
from unittest.mock import call
assert mock_b.call_args == call(4)
```